# Excel VBA Insert/Delete table columns based on a specified cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to show a number of columns in a table based on a number value in cell "C11" on the same worksheet.  The value in C11 is calculated using a formula, so the VBA would need to happen automatically when the source data for the formula is updated on a different sheet.

The data is currently in a table ("Table1") but if it helps, it doesn't have to be.

Cell C11 contains a number of weeks i.e. "6", range "Headers" from "Table1" includes the week number.  The first 2 weeks (So first 2 columns) must always be shown.

I'm currently using this but it doesn't do anything, nor does it throw an error.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim intersectRange As Range
    Set intersectRange = Range("Table1")
    Dim NumExistingColumns As Long
    Dim NumToInsertOrDelete As Long
    Dim TotalsRange As Range

    On Error GoTo EH

    Set KeyCells = Me.Range("Headers")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        ' Validate Entry
        If Not IsNumeric(KeyCells.Value) Then Exit Sub
        intersectRange = KeyCells.Value
        If intersectRange <= 0 Then Exit Sub

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        NumExistingColumns = Me.Cells(2, Me.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 2
        NumToInsertOrDelete = NumColumnsRequired - NumExistingColumns
        Select Case NumToInsertOrDelete
            Case Is < 0
                ' Delete columns
                Me.Columns(2).Resize(, -NumToInsertOrDelete).Delete
            Case Is > 0
                ' Insert columns
                Me.Columns(2).Resize(, NumToInsertOrDelete).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Case 0
                ' No Change
        End Select
    End If
EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you debug the code to check if one of the `Exit Sub`s is triggered?

Comment: Comment out the `On Error GoTo EH` to find any errors hidden.

Comment: Is "Header" a named range ? if yes, is it one cell only or one row across multiple columns ? from `Intersect(KeyCells, Target)` I guess the "Header" named range is across multiple columns ? If yes, I don't think `IsNumeric(KeyCells.Value)` will work as I think it will always be FALSE then it will always go directly exit the sub. If KeyCells is a range variable which is one cell only with value, then `IsNumeric(KeyCells.Value)` will work to either TRUE or FALSE. But from `intersectRange = KeyCells.Value:If intersectRange <= 0` ---> it seems KeyCells variable is only one cell ? Please CMIIW.

Comment: @karma Thanks for the input.  The "Header" range is the header of Table1, so can span multiple columns.  I think the whole code may need to start from scratch, any ideas?

Comment: In the sheet (say, sheet ToBeProcessed) where the process (delete/insert column) will be performed, cell C11 contains a formula where in this formula it has a link to a cell (say cell A1) in another sheet (say, sheet LinkedSheet). If this cell A1 in LinkedSheet is changed by a user, then you want the macro automatically delete/insert column in sheet ToBeProcessed depends on the formula result in C11 of the sheet ToBeProcessed. If that's the case, then I think the `Worksheet_Change` sub need to be in the sheet LinkedSheet module. (continue)

Comment: The sub is triggered when cell A1 in sheet LinkedChange is changed by the user, to check what is the formula result in cell C11 in sheet ToBeProcessed. If C11 formula result value is negative number, then it delete certain column in sheet ToBeProcessed, if the C11 formula result value is positive number then it insert a new column in sheet ToBeProcessed. Something like that ?